# Regex, how can I allow 10 or 11 digit number after slash?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying allow after slash 10 or 11 digit number. It must don't exist string anywhere after slash.

I tried:

```js
let regCode = new RegExp('^[^\\da-zA-Z]*\\d{10,11}[^\\da-zA-Z]*$','g')
console.log(regCode.test("test/1234567890"))
console.log(regCode.test("test/1234567890abc"))
console.log(regCode.test("test/abc1234567a890abc"))
```

Thank you

Comment: `let regCode = new RegExp('/\\d{10,11}$')`?

Comment: `^[^\\da-zA-Z]` does not allow 0-9a-zA-Z at the beginning of the string, thats why it fails

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is solve my problem thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex defined with the help of a `RegExp` constructor notation (so as to avoid escaping `/`):

```js
let regCode = new RegExp('/\\d{10,11}$')
```

Or, with a regex literal (to avoid escaping backslashes twice):

```js
let regCode = /\/\d{10,11}$/
```

Surely, you can also use `[0-9]` instead of `\\d` in the first statement to avoid the "backslash hell".

*Details*:

- `/` - a `/` char
- `\d{10,11}` - ten or eleven digits
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yvZzNL/1).

**Note** the absence of the `g`lobal modifier in the regex, see [Why does a RegExp with global flag give wrong results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1520800/3832970) to understand why.

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
let regCode = new RegExp('/\\d{10,11}$');
console.log("test/1234567890 =>", regCode.test("test/1234567890"))
console.log("test/1234567890abc =>", regCode.test("test/1234567890abc"))
console.log("test/abc1234567a890abc =>", regCode.test("test/abc1234567a890abc"))
```